# Hand Cursor when rolling over MovieClips in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouse

My goal is to simply have the cursor swap to be a hand (pointer) when I roll over a MovieClip. Obviously I could use SimpleButton, but the situation is that I have some enemies that are obviously MovieClips, and when I select an ability to use I want the mouse to show as a pointer when I roll over them.

I assumed this would work:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

mc.graphics.beginFill(0);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
mc.graphics.endFill();

mc.useHandCursor = true; // <---- doesn't work?

addChild(mc);

mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace('a');
}
```

There are workarounds such as adding a button into the enemy MovieClip and then removing it. Just seems there's an inbuilt way I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think it's `mc.buttonMode = true;`

Comment: This helped. `useHandCursor` is actionscript 2.0 it seems

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes you will need to use also :

```
mc.mouseChildren=false;
```

To have handcursor over some movieclips, like movieclip with a textfield inside. -

Comment: if you have mc with textfield (for example menu item), cursor will not be a pointer over textfield (flash bug or something?), so in this case it is a good idea.

Comment: i think it isn't a bug, i think it's deliberate. (which doesn't mean either is a good or a bad thing, but it's food for thought :) )

Comment: Good call on mouseChildren=false, it fixed my problem

Comment: Use static texts inside buttons. So the cursor will not change.

Answer (score 6):

`mc.buttonMode = true;`  You can use this,

this will works.